# How to get specific response headers from ajax request in selenium using python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I want to get the specific headers from ajax request that the website is sending, so the problem is the response headers is not in the page that Im scraping but on the ajax request that this website made

I got response cookie easily with

> cookie = chrome.get_cookie("cookiename")

but for response headers ? I can't find anything on how to get them